# Can't connect to hidden WPA2 hidden network

Tags: wifi, wifi-direct

I am trying to connect to my works hidden network, I know the name of the network and the password but it doesn't want to connect to the network. I can see it when I can and still it will not connect. My phone connects to the network with the same credentials. I am at a loss. I also tried this [one](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup/setting-up-wifi-with-occidentalis) with no connection. I can not amend the work's network. Please advise.

The settings are WPA2-Personal. I even hardcoded the details into the `wpa-supplicant.conf` file and still the same result.

Comment: Anyways, it's solved. For further visitors please add some detail like your wpa-supplicant.conf (of course remove all passwords, hashes, essids and secure data!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reinstalled Respian and then used that link from above and now it works.

my wpa_supplicant.conf file just had these two lines:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

and my config.txt file I did this:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
   wpa-scan-ssid 1
   wpa-ap-scan 1
   wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
   wpa-proto RSN WPA
   wpa-pairwise CCMP TKIP
   wpa-group CCMP TKIP
   wpa-ssid "My Secret SSID"
   wpa-psk "My SSID PSK"

iface default inet dhcp
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.